# Prevent simplification of units in pint

Tags: python, pint

I sometimes use the [`pint` library](https://pint.readthedocs.io/) to display civil engineering calculations.

For these calculations, there are times when I want a quantity displayed a certain way in order to make it clear what the quantity represents. But when using `pint`, the units get automatically reduced, making things less clear.

Some examples:

- "moment per unit length": changed from `kip·ft/ft` to `kip`
- "area per unit length": changed from `in²/in` to `in`
- "moment of inertia per length": changed from `in⁴/in` to `in³`
- "slope": changed from `in/in` to unitless

Code illustrating the first example:

```
>>> import pint
>>> u = pint.UnitRegistry(system='US')
>>> x = 100*u.kip*u.ft/u.ft
>>> f'{x:~P}'
'100.0 kip'
```

Can I prevent this unit simplification, and get the units to display the way I want?

Comment: It appears the answer [might be no](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/issues/389).

Comment: I have the same question with regards to production intensity.  In the corp sustainability space, people want to know the ratio of CO2 emitted per unit of production.  People talk about `t CO2 / t Steel' and are not expecting an intensity metric of 'CO2 / Steel'.